# Fancybox: How to keep a video from auto-advancing

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a Fancybox gallery, with two objects - a video and an image:

http://59plymouth.net/59test/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3357

At the conclusion of the video, Fancybox auto-advances to the image.  I would like for it to remain at the final frame of the video, where the user can choose to advance, or go to the previous object (no previous object in this case).  How can I achieve that?

Comment: *Bump*.  Here's a simpler example - no phpBB board, strictly Fancybox.  A video and an image in my gallery; how do I keep Fancybox from automatically advancing to the image following the end of the video?

http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html

Comment: Well; it turns out, the way to keep a video from auto-advancing, is to keep it from auto-starting.  I removed autoStart: true from jquery.fancybox.js, and that keeps the video from starting automatically (another desired outcome), as well as from advancing to the next object.